# Unity Value Assigned in Inspector Throws Null in Code

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm a beginner at Unity with a problem for which I've not been able to find an answer on any of the boards.  Creating a very basic Unity C# script, I have the following lines of code in my `Awake()` function:

```
Assert.IsNotNull(sfxJump);
Assert.IsNotNull(sfxDeath);
Assert.IsNotNull(sfxCoin);
```

The third assertion "
`Assert.IsNotNull(sfxCoin)` throws as `null`, even though the coin `AudioClip` is set in the Inspector:

Inspector script values:

[image]

However -- and this is the part that has me baffled -- for some reason `sfxCoin` is **not** `null` when invoked in the same script from an `OnCollisionEnter()` routine

So it appears Unity does register the object with the code -- eventually -- but the assertions fail with the initial `Awake()`, `Start()`, and `Update()` methods.

And this only is happening with `sfxCoin`.  `sfxJump` and `sfxDeath` do not have this issue.

Any help would be appreciated

Entire script is below:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Assertions;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float jumpForce = 100f;
    [SerializeField] private float forwardMomentum = 5f;
    [SerializeField] private AudioClip sfxJump;
    [SerializeField] private AudioClip sfxDeath;
    [SerializeField] private AudioClip sfxCoin; 

    private Animator anim;
    private Rigidbody Rigidbody;
    private bool jump = false;
    private AudioSource audioSource;  

    private void Awake()
    {
        Assert.IsNotNull(sfxJump);
        Assert.IsNotNull(sfxDeath);
        Assert.IsNotNull(sfxCoin);
    }

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        Rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (!GameManager.instance.GameOver() && GameManager.instance.GameStarted())
        { 
            if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
            {
                GameManager.instance.PlayerStartedGame();

                anim.Play("Jump");
                audioSource.PlayOneShot(sfxJump);
                Rigidbody.useGravity = true;
                jump = true;
            }
        }
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (jump)
        {
            jump = false;
            Rigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(0, 0);
            Rigidbody.AddForce(new Vector2(forwardMomentum, jumpForce), ForceMode.Impulse);
        }
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        switch (collision.gameObject.tag)
        {
            case "obstacle":
                Rigidbody.AddForce(new Vector2(-50, 20), ForceMode.Impulse);
                Rigidbody.detectCollisions = false;
                audioSource.PlayOneShot(sfxDeath);
                GameManager.instance.PlayerCollided();
                break;
            case "coin":

                audioSource.PlayOneShot(sfxCoin);
                GameManager.instance.Score(1);
                print("GOT COIN");
                break;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your entire script.

Comment: Is it possible that the file format of the clip you're trying to insert could not be loaded via Unity? You can try adding it onto another script, just to see if it runs properly.

Comment: Thanks for replying.    The clip actually is there, and even plays the sound when the OnCollisionEnter() is triggered in the same script.  It comes up as null in Awakw(), Start(), and Update().  It is not null in OnCollisionEnter().

Comment: Just as sidenote: I would do all GetComponent calls always already in `Awake` if possible. This way later other objects could already use them at `Start`

Comment: Try check it with `object.ReferenceEquals(sfxCoin, null)`

Comment: Okay, so I inserted object.ReferenceEquals(sfxCoin, null) immediately after the assertion for sfxCoin.  It throws false.  So what gives here?  Why does the assertion think it's null while object.ReferenceEquals says it isn't?

Comment: I just checked sfxCoin in the debugger.  The Watch says it's null too.

Answer (score 1):

sorry, I found out what the problem was.

There was a second instance of a game object that was also using the same script that did not have sfxCoin set.  It was hidden under a node in the hierarchy so I didn't see it.

Like I said, I'm a beginner at this.